# how to remove error while using /dev/tcp/ for port scanning?

Tags: bash

I am building a port scanner  for a project

```
while  [[ $port -le  100 ]]; 
do
  echo >/dev/tcp/$ipaddr/$port &&
    echo "port $port is open for IP address $ipaddr" 
    (( port++ )) 
done
fi
```

I am getting these errors, when a port is closed. I don't want to display any errors

```
./code.sh: connect: Connection refused
./code.sh: line 21: /dev/tcp/192.168.0.1/1: Connection refused
```

also i tried  running it with 2>/dev/null but it also removes the prompt for which IP to scan
please consider all the variables as declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect the group stderr to /dev/null

```
{ echo >/dev/tcp/$ipaddr/$port; } 2>/dev/null
```